# Rails - Google_Visular column chart bar width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-visualization

I have added some charts using the [google_visular](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/) gem. Im am trying to figure out what is causing my column chart to be created with extremely thin columns when I call an `order` method on my active record statement.

Eg:

code to generate chart:

```
  def self.get_graph(options={})
     data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
      data_table.new_column('datetime', 'Date')
      data_table.new_column('number', "#{options[:model_name]}")
      options[:model_name].where(:generated_at => options[:start_date].beginning_of_day..options[:end_date].end_of_day).each do |p|
          data_table.add_row([p.generated_at.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)'), p.__send__(options[:col_name])])
      end
       opts = { :width => 1100, :height => 280, :chartArea => {:width => 950, :height => 220}, :colors => [options[:color]], :legend => 'none' }
       @chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::ColumnChart.new(data_table, opts)
  end
```

Code to call method:

```
@users_chart  = Graphing.get_graph({:model_name =>  User, :col_name => "users", :start_date => start_date, :end_date => end_date, :color => "#D48F00"})
```

JavaScript Generate:

```
  google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
    var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn({"type":"datetime","label":"Date"});data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","label":"User"});data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 20, 0, 0)}, {v: 182313}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 23, 0, 0)}, {v: 62751}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 17, 0, 0)}, {v: 234533}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 21, 0, 0)}, {v: 132029}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 22, 0, 0)}, {v: 92957}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 19, 0, 0)}, {v: 222587}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 9353}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 18, 0, 0)}, {v: 240253}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 10, 0, 0)}, {v: 240635}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 14, 0, 0)}, {v: 225663}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 1, 0, 0)}, {v: 34734}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 16, 0, 0)}, {v: 213179}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 2, 0, 0)}, {v: 31031}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 9, 0, 0)}, {v: 231830}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 12, 0, 0)}, {v: 247994}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 4, 0, 0)}, {v: 63644}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 6, 0, 0)}, {v: 151377}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 11, 0, 0)}, {v: 252827}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 13, 0, 0)}, {v: 244994}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 5, 0, 0)}, {v: 107412}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 15, 0, 0)}, {v: 214306}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 41760}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 8, 0, 0)}, {v: 199565}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 3, 0, 0)}, {v: 40525}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 7, 0, 0)}, {v: 185940}]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('users_chart'));
    chart.draw(data_table, {width: 1100, height: 280, chartArea: {width: 950, height: 220}, colors: ["#D48F00"], legend: "none"});
  }});
```

Output:
[image: Output without order clause]

However if i change my where method to include the order eg:

```
def self.get_graph(options={})
         data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
          data_table.new_column('datetime', 'Date')
          data_table.new_column('number', "#{options[:model_name]}")
          options[:model_name].where(:generated_at => options[:start_date].beginning_of_day..options[:end_date].end_of_day).order('generated_at ASC').each do |p|
              data_table.add_row([p.generated_at.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)'), p.__send__(options[:col_name])])
          end
           opts = { :width => 1100, :height => 280, :chartArea => {:width => 950, :height => 220}, :colors => [options[:color]], :legend => 'none' }
           @chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::ColumnChart.new(data_table, opts)
      end
```

JavaScript generated:

```
  google.load('visualization','1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
    var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();data_table.addColumn({"type":"datetime","label":"Date"});data_table.addColumn({"type":"number","label":"User"});data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 17, 0, 0)}, {v: 234533}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 18, 0, 0)}, {v: 240253}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 19, 0, 0)}, {v: 222587}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 20, 0, 0)}, {v: 182313}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 21, 0, 0)}, {v: 132029}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 22, 0, 0)}, {v: 92957}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 29, 23, 0, 0)}, {v: 62751}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 9353}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 41760}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 1, 0, 0)}, {v: 34734}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 2, 0, 0)}, {v: 31031}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 3, 0, 0)}, {v: 40525}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 4, 0, 0)}, {v: 63644}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 5, 0, 0)}, {v: 107412}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 6, 0, 0)}, {v: 151377}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 7, 0, 0)}, {v: 185940}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 8, 0, 0)}, {v: 199565}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 9, 0, 0)}, {v: 231830}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 10, 0, 0)}, {v: 240635}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 11, 0, 0)}, {v: 252827}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 12, 0, 0)}, {v: 247994}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 13, 0, 0)}, {v: 244994}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 14, 0, 0)}, {v: 225663}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 15, 0, 0)}, {v: 214306}]);data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 16, 0, 0)}, {v: 213179}]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('users_chart'));
    chart.draw(data_table, {width: 1100, height: 280, chartArea: {width: 950, height: 220}, bar_groupWidth: "80%", colors: ["#D48F00"], legend: "none"});
  }});
```

The generated chart looks like:
[image: Image with order clause]

What can I do to fix this? ( I need the order clause on there so that the charts timescale is linear)

Comment: I can't help you with the Ruby end of things, but if you can post the javascript generated by your server code (both with and without the ordering applied), I can take a look and see what might be causing the problem there, which could help you find the error in Ruby.

Comment: Added JS output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ending up with two rows of data for a single point in time:

```
data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 9353}]);
data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 6, 30, 0, 0, 0)}, {v: 41760}]);
```

which is causing the bars to draw so narrowly.  You can see the results with both lines in place (http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/zHwnb/) vs one line commented out (http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/zHwnb/1/).

Fix the duplicate line problem and you will fix the bar width problem.

Incidentally, the bar group width option is specified incorrectly, it should be `bar:{groupWidth:"80%"}`, not `bar_groupWidth: "80%"`, but you shouldn't need to use that once you have fixed the rest.